# Create horizontal buttons with images and labels under them with HTML5

Tags: html, css

Trying to create three horizontal buttons with images and labels under them with HTML5.
Tryed the following example: [tutorial](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/cssdrive_horizontal_menu_buttons) , but I need different image for each button.

If i give each button id and add to css #id {background-image:url} i see only part of image instead of image stretched to button size.

Answer (score 0):

I copied some of the code from the target site. Note the height and width below

```
...

width: 78px;

height: 23px;

...

background-image:url(tabsquare.jpg);

...

}

.hbuttons a:hover{

background-image:url(tabsquareover.jpg);

}
```

It does not stretch the image. It make a box 78px x 23px. It then puts the image in the background. If you want the image to cover 78px x 23px it should be 78px x 23px. Background-images are different from the `<img>` tag.

Comment: So there is no option to make image to fit bounds of button? and how do i add labels under these buttons?

Comment: <img> tag can force an image to be something other than its natural size. With <div>'s and <br>'s you can make a box and force the text underneath. I would recommend a) make an image the size you want. Make the .hbuttons a{} have the size you want. Then add the text on top of that

Answer (score 0):

You can create three different class name for three button and set the css background image what ever you want.

```
<button class="hbuttons">and</button>
<button class="buttons">and</button>
<button class="hbutton">and</button>
```

or

```
 <div>
 <a class="hbutton" href="http://www.cssdrive.com">Home </a>
 <a class="buttons" href="http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/submit/">Submit </a>
 <a class="hbuttons" href="http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/contact/">Contact </a>
 </div>
  <div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

Here the demo: [***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ah9a/)